# How can I get 5K output

Tags: display-resolution, thunderbolt

I've got a precision 5510 hooked up with a Dell UP2715K 5K monitor via a Plugable Thunderbolt 3 display adapter which outputs to dual display ports (which is how the monitor receives 5K input). It provides 5K output on Windows, but on Linux, the resolution options top out at 4K. Is there some xrandr / xorg trick to get 5K as a resolution I can choose? I'm on Ubuntu 16.10 with the 4.8.1 kernel.

Answer (score 1):

The dell 5k is recognized as two separate displays. Try to set the resolution of both to 2560x2880. As far as I know currently there exists a "syncing issue" between these panels in linux. The bug is currently in works here: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97244

As a workaround you might be able to set up xinerama (I have done this with 16.04 on my stationary pc setup with nvidia 960)